# SocketIO not functioning, no console messages showing

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

I am designing a chat application in Flask. Following is the code:

> Part of Python code which handles event

```
@socketio.on('new channel created')
def new_channel(channel_name):
    channels.append(channel_name["channel_name"])
    print(channels)
    emit('display new channel',{"channel_name": channel_name["channel_name"]},broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

`channels` is a list which contains name of all the channels created. Even though I appended a channel in the list but in the next line when I print, it doesn't show anything.

> JavaScript code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        document.querySelector('#submit_channel').onclick = () =>{
            const channel_name=document.querySelector('[name="channel_name"]').value;
            console.log("connection msg");
            socket.emit('new channel created',{'channel_name': channel_name});
        };
    });

    socket.on('display new channel', cn => {
        const li=document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML=document.querySelector(`[name="${cn.channel_name}"]`).value
        document.querySelector('#channel_list').append(li);
        console.log("some message");

    });
        
});
```

I have `<ul>` in html where `<li>` is appended.
The problem that I face is `<li>` tags that I am adding are not reflecting to all clients but only to the one who has made it although I have given `broadcast=True` in `emit`. A button is clicked which is not a part of a `<form>` which triggers the onclick event as in JS code. Other thing is that the console messages are not printing. The `<li>` tags are added in client who is creating them, that is these functions might be running, but it doesn't print console messages makes it doubtful. Please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was all problem of the cache, my browser had cached the page and was giving the same results every time. It was not reflecting the changes that I had been making. I removed cache and tried to run again it works fine now.